# Can a Stackholder access a version controlled file in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

I know a Stakeholder doesn't have access to the most of the code related things in VSTS. But, can he/she access a single file in a read-only mode which is in the code? Let's say for example a `readme.md` file.

Comment: No, users who have stackholder access level to the VSTS account can not read any files in code (repositoies).

Answer (score 0):

No, but a markdown file can be pinned to the team's dashboard with the [markdown widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/add-markdown-to-dashboard?view=vsts&tabs=new-query-exp) or used as a wiki, which should work even for stakeholders.